# SharePoint Add-in has "Full Control" on "Web" level but is not able to access sub web lists

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint Add-in which has the following App Permissions defined in the AppManifest.xml.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false" >
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/taxonomy" Right="Write" />
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**To avoid the user needing "site collection administrator" permissions**, the "AllowAppOnlyPolicy" is set to false.

The purpose of the app is creating a subsite under which all the needed info is stored. I am able to create the subsite without an issue, but from the moment I try to access lists in the subsite, I'm getting an *"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."* exception.
Which I found quite surprising since I expected that if you have "Full Control" on a site, you would also have access to the subsites.

Is there a way to access the lists of a subsite without having to add the site collection read permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you misunderstood the concept of *AllowAppOnlyPolicy*.
The AppOnlyPolicy actually enables you to override the users permissions and let SharePoint only check the permissions granted to the AddIn (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/app-only-elevated-privileges-sharepoint-add-in)), so actually what you wanted. You need to change to:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" >
```

Why in the first step you can create the subsite, for me only has one possible explanation: That your service account or the users account has the required permissions to do that on that web. (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21193/creating-sub-sites).

Comment: My outcome is that as a user with full control rights, I'm able to add the add-in on a site and that from that add-in I'm then able to create a subsite. On which I also have "Full Control"

To use the "AllowAppOnlyPolicy" as you suggested is not an option for me, since from the moment I put it on, the user that adds the add-in must have site collection administrator rights.

I'm also not sure that even if I use it, I will have the same rights on the subsite and the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Give a permission of Full Control to Site Collection and Tenant as well from the App Manifest. That would help.

Comment: I want a normal user to be able to add the add-in. The whole purpose was to not give this much rights, otherwise only site collection administrators can add the add-in.